# Minimize the distance between two vectors depending on parameters

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have two vectors:

```
u = [2, 3, 5, 12, 16, 17, 29]
v = [v1, v2, v3, v1+v2, v1+v3, v2+v3, v1+v2+v3]
```

for example. Now, I am interested in finding the values `[v1, v2, v3]` by some optimization method, the idea being that, getting the vector `v` as close to `u` as possible, the parameters of `v` will be good enough for my purposes.

This looks a bit like a [quadratic program](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1591580/optimization-problem-find-shortest-distance-between-two-vectors), however I have no idea how to incorporate my constraints:

1. the elements of `v` are combinations (as shown above), so not independent.
2. the last element of `v`, namely $\sum_{i}v_i = u_{last}$, where $u_{last}$ is the last element of the vector `u`.

Can this be formulated as some optimization problem ?

I was thinking of starting with v1 = v2 = v3 = $\frac{u_{last}}{3}$ and incrementally changing the value of these parameters as I reduce the distance between the two vectors.

Comment: I doubt a canned package will do it, but it should be easy enough to do directly.  Define a function $F(v_1,v_2,v_3)=\sum_{i=1}^7 (\vec {v_i}-\vec {x_i})^2$ and solve for $\nabla F = \vec 0$.

Comment: Note:  the notation is a bit confusing.  I used your $v_1,v_2,v_3$ for the arguments for $F$ but these are different from $\vec {v_i}$ (though they coincide for $i=1,2,3$).  For instance $\vec {v_4}=v_1+v_2$.

Comment: Or review, I think I skipped a constraint.  You insist that $v_1+v_2+v_3=29$?  In that case you can eliminate $v_3$ from the problem and you are down to two variables.  Even easier.

Comment: @lulu Hi, and thanks for your suggestion. Yes, the sum of v's must be equal to the last element of u. However, how can I "solve" for grad(F) = 0 ? Gradient descent or you have something else in mind?

Comment: It's just a pair of linear equations in two variables.  No need for anything complicated.

Comment: Have you done it?  I get $(v_1,v_2)=(8,9)$.  I did it hastily, with pen and paper, so I might have gotten it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have $v_1+v_2+v_3=29$ we can eliminate $v_3$ via $$v_3=29-v_1-v_2$$

We then seek the minimum of the function $$G(v_1,v_2)=(v_1-2)^2+(v_2-3)^2+(v_1+v_2-24)^2+(v_1+v_2-12)^2+(v_2-13)^2+(v_1-12)^2$$

This can be found by setting $\nabla G = (0,0)$ and solving the resultant pair of linear equations.  I get $$\boxed {(v_1,v_2)=(8,9)}$$

and simple numerical calculations confirm that small perturbations of this increase the value of $G$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am however looking for an algorithm that would be able to solve this, or approximate, for a very large number of dimensions. I have specifically chosen 3 parameters for v here for clarity, but in my problem I can have 100 or 500.

Comment: This method is entirely general and would work in very high dimensions.  To be clear, this is just ordinary least squares analysis, adapted to the fact that your variables have some fixed linear relations between them.  I really do not believe you will find an easier computational approach.